# how to transform changing data to be visualized in a chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am using a url to fetch data that constantly updates and changes. It comes back in the form of an array like this:

`[[0,14],[1,11],[2,15],[3,12],[4,8],[5,8],[6,9],[7,9],[8,9],[9,7]]`.

I would like this to be transformed so I can use it in a `chart.js`

I think I should convert it to a json file, but don't really know how it works because the fetch needs to be initialized every 5 seconds and that new data has to be put in the json file every time and then displayed in the `chart.js`.

I got the data in the `updatingArray[]`, but i'm stuck now.

```
function getDataFromDatapointsUrl(){
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = 'https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php)';

fetch(proxyurl + url)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(contents => createArrayForUpdatingData(contents));
    }

getDataFromDatapointsUrl();

// setInterval(getDataFromDatapointsUrl, 500);
var updatingDataArray = [];

function createArrayForUpdatingData(updatingData){
    updatingDataArray.push(updatingData);
}
```

I would like the data from the array to be split up in the chart.

`[[0,14],[1,11],[2,15],[3,12],[4,8],[5,8],[6,9],[7,9],[8,9],[9,7]]`.

So the `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...` should become the x-axis and the 14,11,15, ... should become the value of the chart-line, bar-, pie, whatever you like it to visualized like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you can simply iterate `updatingDataArray` and push each value to a separate array that you then pass to Chart.js:

```js
var updatingDataArray = [
  [0, 14],
  [1, 11],
  [2, 15],
  [3, 12],
  [4, 8],
  [5, 8],
  [6, 9],
  [7, 9],
  [8, 9],
  [9, 7]
];

var labels = [],
  values = [];

updatingDataArray.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  labels.push(val[0]);
  values.push(val[1]);
});

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: values
    }]
  },
  options: {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```